# Using defined names in Excel with COUNTIF

Tags: excel, drop-down-menu, names, defined

My example has been shortened for this question, also note that the total for each heading does not exist and is there for the indication only.

I have many drop down lists with the options Yes or No and I wish to find the total of them using `=COUNTIF(DropLists, "Yes")` where DropLists is a defined name with the referral `=Sheet1!$B$2:$B$3,Sheet1!$B$6:$B$8`. Not included in the example, I have other items in the same column so I cannot just use the entire column.

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong, but the error I get in the total is `#VALUE`. The attached screenshot has borders around the lists which are all part of the DropLists name.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Define DropLists as one, contiguous range.

Comment: @Gary'sStudent I have other items between them in the same column

Comment: That's O.K. as long as the items don't include "Yes"

Comment: @Gary'sStudent is there no other way, incase they include "Yes"? I would like to use this method to total up the lists and construct some other formula too.

Comment: COUNTIF only accepts a single range as first argument - you can't circumvent that by using a named range to join discrete ranges

Answer (score 0):

You should simply **make one CountIf for each of you ranges and make the sum of the results** of all these CountIfs...

```
=COUNTIF(droplist1,"Yes")+COUNTIF(droplist2,"Yes")+...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have Excel 2007 or later and your data follows the apparent pattern of having a Sub# in column A and a Yes/No in column B then you can use

`COUNTIFS(criteria_range1, criteria1, [criteria_range2, criteria2]…)`

like this

```
    =COUNTIFS(A:A,"Sub*",B:B,"Yes")
```

The  `=COUNTIFS` function will take wildcards so  the `"Sub*"` criteria will limit the initial count of column A to cells that starts with "Sub".  `"Yes"` refines the count to what you are looking for I think.